# Sonar runner is failing - Error while creating file [90062-167]

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am running in to some issues when running sonar server (on a remote dev machine) abd then trying to run sonar runner on my machine on a simple project.

I dont understand the error message, of course i can see it cant connect to the database but i dont fully understand why its trying to create a file or why it would be an empty file path or what not

Please could someone help me understand this error message?

```
 > Sonar Runner 2.2 Java 1.7.0_15 Oracle Corporation (32-bit) Windows 7
    > 6.1 x86 INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Users\...\workspace\java-sonar-runner-si
    > mple\sonar-runner-2.2\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties INFO:
    > Project configuration file:
    > C:\Users\...\workspace\java-sonar-runner-s
    > imple\sonar-runner-2.2\bin\sonar-project.properties INFO: Default
    > locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8" INFO: Work directory:
    > C:\Users\...\workspace\java-sonar-runner-simple\sonar-
    > runner-2.2\bin\.sonar INFO: Sonar Server 3.2 10:59:08.438 WARN  - H2
    > database should be used for evaluation purpose only 10:59:08.441 INFO 
    > - Create JDBC datasource to url jdbc:h2://169.168.66.20:9092/ sonar INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 12.333s Final Memory: 2M/15M INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution ERROR: Unable to execute
    > Sonar ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database ERROR: Caused by:
    > Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Error while creating file
    > "//" [90062-167]) ERROR: Caused by: Error while creating file "//"
    > [90062-167] ERROR: ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors,
    > re-run Sonar Runner with the - e switch. ERROR: Re-run Sonar Runner
    > using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

**sonar properties file**

```
#--------------------------------------------------------
# This file must contain only ISO 8859-1 characters
# see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)
#
# To use an environment variable, use the following syntax :  ${env:NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE}
# For example :
#   sonar.jdbc.url: ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
#
#
# See also the file conf/wrapper.conf for JVM advanced settings
#---------------------------------------------------------


#---------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SETTINGS - STANDALONE MODE ONLY
# These settings are ignored when the war file is deployed to a JEE server.
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Listen host/port and context path (for example / or /sonar). Default values are 0.0.0.0:9000/.
#sonar.web.host:                           0.0.0.0
#sonar.web.port:                           9000
#sonar.web.context:                        /

# Log HTTP requests. Deactivated by default.
#sonar.web.jettyRequestLogs: ../../logs/jetty-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT : the embedded database H2 is used by default. 
# It is recommended for tests only. Please use an external database
# for production environment (MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql, SQLServer)
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#----- Credentials
# Permissions to create tables and indexes must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar

#----- Embedded database H2
# Note : it does not accept connections from remote hosts, so the
# sonar server and the maven plugin must be executed on the same host.

# Comment the following line to deactivate the default embedded database.
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver

# directory containing H2 database files. By default it's the /data directory in the sonar installation.
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.dataDir:
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               9092


#----- MySQL 5.x/6.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line to use MySQL
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


#----- Oracle 10g/11g
# To connect to Oracle database :
#
# - It's recommended to use the latest version of the JDBC driver (either ojdbc6.jar for Java 6 or ojdbc5.jar for Java 5).
#   Download it in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html
# - Copy the driver to the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line :
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# Uncomment the following property if the Oracle account has permissions to access multiple schemas,
# for example sonar schemas with different versions. In that case, use the same property during project analysis
# (-Dsonar.jdbc.schema=<schema>)
#sonar.jdbc.schema:                         sonar


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following property to use PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.postgresql.Driver

# Uncomment the following property if the PostgreSQL account has permissions to access multiple schemas,
# for example sonar schemas with different versions. In that case, use the same property during project analysis
# (-Dsonar.jdbc.schema=<schema>)
#sonar.jdbc.schema:                         public


#----- Microsoft SQLServer
# The Jtds open source driver is available in extensions/jdbc-driver/mssql. More details on http://jtds.sourceforge.net
#sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

# Optional properties
#sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver


#----- Connection pool settings
sonar.jdbc.maxActive:                      20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle:                        5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle:                        2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait:                        5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis:     600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  30000
```

> ```
> #---------------------------------------------------------
> # UPDATE CENTER
> #---------------------------------------------------------
>
> # The Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
> # It is activated by default:
> #sonar.updatecenter.activate=true
>
> # HTTP proxy (default none)
> #http.proxyHost=
> #http.proxyPort=
>
> # NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
> #http.auth.ntlm.domain=
>
> # SOCKS proxy (default none)
> #socksProxyHost=
> #socksProxyPort=
>
> # proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
> #http.proxyUser=
> #http.proxyPassword=
>
> #---------------------------------------------------------
> # NOTIFICATIONS
> #---------------------------------------------------------
>
> # Delay (in seconds) between processing of notification queue
> sonar.notifications.delay=60
> ```
>
> **full error log**

```
> 
> INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 6.372s Final Memory: 2M/15M INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
> org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>         at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
> .java:79)
>         at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:63)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
>         at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>         at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:71)
> 
>         at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:89)
>         at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>         at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>         at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
>         at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java
> :72)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
> java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
> sorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>         at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(
> ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
>         at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(Reflect
> ionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
>         at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter
> .start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
>         at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.j
> ava:169)
>         at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Store
> d.java:132)
>         at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
>         at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(Defaul
> tPicoContainer.java:1009)
>         at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoConta
> iner.java:1002)
>         at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.jav
> a:760)
>         at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
> ntainer.java:70)
>         at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:82)
>         at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:73)
>         at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:60)
>         at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java
> :45)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
> java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
> sorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>         at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
> .java:75)
>         ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableCon
> nectionFactory (Error while creating file "//" [90062-167])
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
> ry(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
> rce.java:1388)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.
> java:1098)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(Basic
> DataSourceFactory.java:350)
>         at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultData
> base.java:122)
>         at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java
> :67)
>         ... 32 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file "//" [90062-1 67]
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
>         at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:247)
>         at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectory(FileUtils.java:46)
>         at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:300)
>         at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.createDirectories(FileUtils.java:299)
>         at org.h2.store.FileLock.lockFile(FileLock.java:326)
>         at org.h2.store.FileLock.lock(FileLock.java:128)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:542)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.jav
> a:305)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
>         at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(Driv
> erConnectionFactory.java:38)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(Poolable
> ConnectionFactory.java:582)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Bas
> icDataSource.java:1556)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFacto
> ry(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>         ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the sonar.config file since i'd be interested to see your h2 database settings. H2 is going to create files as part of its initialisation so perhaps there are file write permission issues with the config path.

I'd suggesting editing the

```
 sonar.embeddedDatabase.dataDir
```

value and point it to a folder location you know is writable. Where do you have your sonar package installed?

Comment: added the sonar server config file to the original post. is this the file you mean?

Comment: OK - thanks. It looks ok. have you tried running with the -X debug mode on to see the extra exception details in the log file?

Comment: Yes - have posted the full log now

Comment: thanks  - see the edit. still suspect file write permission issues even if the stacktrace doesn't indicate this clearly.